# How to properly setup OpenSSL for Qt on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, openssl

I've downloaded and installed OpenSSL from this link: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Then I added the following line to my .pro file:

```
LIBS += -LC:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib -llibcrypto -llibssl
```

I can confirm QT is able to link the libs because if I put a random letter on their name it fails the build saying that said lib was not found

Then I copied "libcrypto-1_1.dll" and "libssl-1_1.dll" from the OpenSSL bin folder to my application folder.

I added `#include <QSslSocket>` to my file, but when I call `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` it always return false. What I'm doing wrong?

Note: I'm clearing the project between builds to assure QT is using the lastest changes

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by following this step:

> The OpenSSL libraries are looked up first in the directory of the
> executable, then in the Windows System directory (usually
> C:\Windows\system32), and finally in all directories listed in the
> PATH environment variable.

Once I copied the dlls to system32 folders it started working (even though I had them on PATH variable AND executable folder)

More info can be found here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html